# SQL Join Query for 3 tables

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with a join query to pull data from 3 different tables which have common columns between each 2 tables. The queries are below:

```
Query1 = Select * from abc.table1 -- The following are the columns: ID, CODE, DATE, SESSIONTIME.
Query2 = Select * from abc.table3 -- The following are the columns: CODE, Name, BATCH.
Query3 = Select * from abc.table2 -- The following are the columns: BATCH, TITLE
```

I want a join query to display: `CODE`, `DATE`, `SESSIONTIME`, `BATCH`, `TITLE`.
DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inner join with 3 tables in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013364/inner-join-with-3-tables-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.code, t1.date, t1.sessiontime, t2.batch, t3.title
from abc.table1 t1 (nolock) 
left outer join abc.table2 t2 (nolock) on t1.code=t2.code
left outer join abc.table3 t3 (nolock) on t2.batch=t3.batch
```

Comment: Non-standard SQL (nolock), and no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.