# Inner join with of 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables which I am trying to join using the sample in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013364/inner-join-with-3-tables-in-mysql) question. However I am getting below error.

Error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'referrer.Referrer_Name' in 'field list'
```

Code:

```
    SELECT pupils.Pupils_Surname, 
            pupils.Pupils_FirstName,
            referrer.Referrer_Name, 
            progress_track.test_1,  
            progress_track.test_2, 
            progress_track.test_3, 
            progress_track.test_4, 
            progress_track.test_5, 
            progress_track.test_6, 
            progress_track.test_7, 
            progress_track.test_8, 
            progress_track.test_9, 
            progress_track.test_10
    FROM pupils
    INNER JOIN progress_track ON progress_track.Progress_Report_Pupils_ID=pupils.Pupils_ID;
    INNER JOIN referrer ON  pupils.Pupils_Referrer, referrer.Referrer_ID ;
```

Comment: Please post the related tables' `create table code`

Comment: There's a semicolon after the first inner join. So your query missed this line (`INNER JOIN referrer ON  pupils.Pupils_Referrer, referrer.Referrer_ID ;`)

Comment: Please make sure a column name: Referrer_Name in the "referrer" table is exists or not. I thourght you have to remove the semi colon for the first inner join reference.

Comment: INNER JOIN referrer ON  pupils.Pupils_Referrer, referrer.Referrer_ID ;

It Should be INNER JOIN referrer ON  pupils.Referrer_ID=referrer.Referrer_ID 

if pupils table have Referrer_ID

Comment: @1000111: I removed the semicolor. The code still shows same error.

Comment: Change the last line too ` INNER JOIN referrer ON  pupils.Pupils_Referrer = referrer.Referrer_ID ;`

Comment: @1000111: Could you please post this as an answer. It worked but it still did not show any data from the referrer table.

Comment: If the join condition doesn't meet then there's no way you can see data unless you use `LEFT JOIN`. Please check your data first.

Comment: Please ensure that you have data which meets these two conditions : `progress_track.Progress_Report_Pupils_ID = pupils.Pupils_ID

referrer.Referrer_ID = pupils.Pupils_Referrer`

Comment: @1000111: Your comment " Change the last line too  'INNER JOIN referrer ON pupils.Pupils_Referrer = referrer.Referrer_ID ;' worked. Could you please post this as an answer so I can upvote and accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just delete the question. Typos are off topic for stack exchange

Comment: @Strawberry: I am likely not to do that since deleting a lot of questions starts the question feature to be blocked.

Comment: Do you delete a lot of questions?

Comment: I used to but I have stopped doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me highlight the **faults** in your query:

1) The query ended unexpectedly for a **typo**

2) The last `INNER JOIN` contained **syntax error**.

I've highlighted the **faults** in the image given below:

[image]

**Remedy:**

```
SELECT
    pupils.Pupils_Surname,
    pupils.Pupils_FirstName,
    referrer.Referrer_Name,
    progress_track.test_1,
    progress_track.test_2,
    progress_track.test_3,
    progress_track.test_4,
    progress_track.test_5,
    progress_track.test_6,
    progress_track.test_7,
    progress_track.test_8,
    progress_track.test_9,
    progress_track.test_10
FROM
    pupils
INNER JOIN progress_track ON progress_track.Progress_Report_Pupils_ID = pupils.Pupils_ID
INNER JOIN referrer ON pupils.Pupils_Referrer = referrer.Referrer_ID;
```

**In response to your comment:**

> Could you please post this as an answer. It worked but it still did
>   not show any data from the referrer table

- If the join condition doesn't meet then there's no way you can see
  data unless you use `LEFT JOIN`. Please check your data first.
- Please ensure that you have data which meets these two conditions :
  `progress_track.Progress_Report_Pupils_ID = pupils.Pupils_ID
  referrer.Referrer_ID = pupils.Pupils_Referrer`

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the semicolon at the end of the first inner join statement. Because, the query is tried to terminate the statement after the first semicolon of the query itself. So, this is the reason for the column Referrer_Name is not referring the table:"referrer".

**original:**

> FROM pupils
>       INNER JOIN progress_track ON progress_track.Progress_Report_Pupils_ID=pupils.**Pupils_ID;**
>       INNER JOIN referrer ON  pupils.Pupils_Referrer, referrer.Referrer_ID ;

**Use this:**

> FROM pupils
>       INNER JOIN progress_track ON progress_track.Progress_Report_Pupils_ID=pupils.**Pupils_ID**
>       INNER JOIN referrer ON  pupils.Pupils_Referrer = referrer.Referrer_ID ;