# Custom CMS how to create categories for posts with PHP/MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, categories

I am searching all around the internet but I can't seem to find a simple tutorial that can help me with my custom CMS I am building.

I'd like to add multiple categories to my posts.

For example:

```
Title: post 1 
Content: content goes here 
Categories: Technology, Computers, Science, Internet

Title: post 2 
Content: content goes here 
Categories: Music, Jazz, Classic
```

So this is what I have to post my articles

**My database structure**

```
postID | postTitle | postDesc | postCont | postDate


1   Post 1      info1   content1    date1
2   Post 2      info2   content2    date2
3   Post 3      info2   content3    date3
```

**The FORM**

```
<form action='' method='post'>

<p><label>Title</label><br />
<input type='text' name='postTitle' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postTitle'];}?>'></p>

<p><label>Description</label><br />
<textarea name='postDesc' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postDesc'];}?></textarea></p>

<p><label>Content</label><br />
<textarea name='postCont' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postCont'];}?></textarea></p>

<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>

</form>
```

**the PHP code to place it in the database**

```
//insert into database
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_posts (postTitle,postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES (:postImage, :postTitle, :postDesc, :postCont, :postDate)') ;
$stmt->execute(array(
':postTitle' => $postTitle,
':postDesc' => $postDesc,
':postCont' => $postCont,
':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
));

//redirect to index page
header('Location: index.php?action=added');
exit;
```

Comment: I think you are looking for database structure,it depends on your requirements. But I am writing what I guess from your requirements. `post_tbl` it contains all post related data. `category_tbl` it contains all categories with auto_increment ids, third `post_cat_rel_tbl` it contains post id with category id. it may contain multiple rows for single post if there are more than one category. this is one kind of structure. You can modify according to your requirements.

Comment: thanks for your reply,

my php knowledge isn't that great. How can i join the tables?

Comment: It's big topic. Can't tell here, see these links, http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673338/mysql-inner-join-query-multiple-tables and try google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of the basic principle of **Many to Many Relationships** that is suitable for this task. A many to many relationship is a design pattern between two tables when one or more rows in one table may be associated with more than one row in the another table. The relationship between two tables is stored in a third table that stores the primary keys of each relationship ( `postID` and `categoryID` columns ).

Examples of database tables:

```
post

postID | postTitle | postDesc | postCont | postDate

1    Post 1    info1    content1    date1
2    Post 2    info2    content2    date2
3    Post 3    info2    content3    date3

post_category

postID | categoryID

1    1
2    5
3    1
2    6
3    3
2    7
1    2
1    3
1    4

category

categoryID | categoryTitle

1    Technology
2    Computers
3    Science
4    Internet
5    Music
6    Jazz
7    Classic
```

Examples of MySQL queries:

```
MySQL query to get all categories related to post

SELECT * FROM `category` NATURAL JOIN `post_category` WHERE postID=1

categoryID | categoryTitle | postID 

1    Technology    1
2    Computers     1
3    Science       1
4    Internet      1

MySQL query for all posts of the category

SELECT * FROM `post` NATURAL JOIN `post_category` WHERE categoryID=1

postID | postTitle | postDesc | postCont | postDate | categoryID 

1    Post 1    info1    content1    date1    1
3    Post 3    info2    content3    date3    1
```

Comment: Your the man!! thanks i have connected certain categories to certain posts but now maybe i am just being stupid but how do i attach multiple categories to a certain post? i.e.

I have posts 1 and it has category Music (5) and category Jazz (6) and also category Classic (7)

How do i do that? Thanks for the help so far!!