# Need help to INNER JOIN multiple tables and use last value row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 3 tables as follow:

**comments**

```
|id| |uid| |tid|
```

**tracks**

```
|id| |uid|
```

**notifications**

```
|id| |from| |tox|
```

How can I `UPDATE notifications` and `SET tox` as equal to the `tracks.uid` of its relative `tracks.id` that is equal to the last `comments.tid` value?

I tried this without success:

```
UPDATE notifications SET tox = (
  SELECT uid FROM tracks 
  INNER JOIN comments ON tracks.id = comments.tid ORDER BY comments.tid DESC LIMIT 1
  WHERE comments.tid=tracks.id)
WHERE tox = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**UPDATE**

First I edit and moved the `ORDER BY` at the end as suggested. After that I got a different error `1052 - Column 'typeid' in field list is ambiguous`.

I solved it like:

```
UPDATE `notifications` SET `tox` = (
  SELECT tracks.uid FROM `tracks` 
  INNER JOIN `comments` ON tracks.id = comments.tid 
  ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE `tox` = 0 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Inner Join Query Multiple Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673338/mysql-inner-join-query-multiple-tables)

Comment: You are updated tox column which reference of other table. How identify of dependancy.

Comment: @MukeshKalgude everything starts from last row of `comments` where the `tid` value is = to the `tracks.id` related to the `tracks.uid` that is what I need. `tracks.id` is a primary key as `comments.id` and `notifications.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the syntax of the subquery:

```
UPDATE notifications
    SET tox = (SELECT uid
               FROM tracks INNER JOIN
                    comments
                    ON tracks.id = comments.tid
               WHERE comments.tid=tracks.id
               ORDER BY comments.tid DESC
               LIMIT 1
              )
    WHERE tox = 0
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

The `ORDER BY` always goes after the `WHERE`.

Comment: I get another error: `#1052 - Column 'uid' in field list is ambiguous`...should I write `SELECT tracks.uid` instead?

Comment: yes it works now! I update my question with the final code