# How to join 4 tables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a form for search meeting date. The default form display is showing data only today = now(). How can i make query for searching meeting date include 4 tables (every table have one same column : **creadate**)
[image: Here's my form]

Comment: Use the `INNER JOIN` statement. Read here how to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673338/mysql-inner-join-query-multiple-tables

Comment: put here your table structure here

Comment: You join 4 tables the same way you join 2 tables. Just add more `INNER JOIN` clauses that list each table and the joining criteria with the previous tables.

Comment: $view=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_prod INNER JOIN tb_assy ON tb_prod.creadate=tb_assy.creadate INNER JOIN tb_ppc_whs ON tb_assy.creadate=tb_ppc_whs.creadate INNER JOIN tb_ppc_status ON tb_ppc_whs.creadate=tb_ppc_status.creadate WHERE creadate LIKE DATE_FORMAT('".$_GET['tgl1']." 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d')") or die (mysql_error());     --but it cause ambiguous 'creadate' how can i solve this?

Comment: I know this may sound rude, but I'd advice not to write that query yet. It seems you don't know how databases work and how tables are related. Get yourself a book or tutorial on SQL and learn the very basics at least. Only then start applying this on your database.

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code..

```
SELECT M.*,A.*,W.*,D.* FROM Mch as M
    INNER JOIN Assy as A ON M.creadate=A.creadate 
    INNER JOIN WHS as W ON A.creadate=W.creadate 
    INNER JOIN DLV as D ON W.creadate=D.creadate
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar said, you just add more `INNER JOIN`.

So it would end up something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Mch 
    INNER JOIN Assy ON Mch.creadate=Assy.creadate 
    INNER JOIN WHS ON Assy.creadate=WHS.creadate 
    INNER JOIN DLV ON WHS.creadate=DLV.creadate
```

Comment: I've tried using inner join but data always show in Mch table form only, not showing in all table form.

Comment: I think your problem might be in the way you are displaying the tables in php and not in the mysql query itself. Maybe you should show us how you're doing that