# INNER JOIN SQL ORDER BY NOT WORKING

Tags: mysql, sql

WORKING!

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT(rs.id_segreto) as tot
FROM Segreti s INNER JOIN
     Reazioni_Segreti rs
     ON s.id = rs.id_segreto
WHERE rs.tipo_reazione = 'mi_piace'
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY tot DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But it print me only 1 row.

```
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['id']."<br>";
}
```

Why happened? What i wrong?

Comment: refer to this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673338/mysql-inner-join-query-multiple-tables

Comment: Can you give us some sample data from the two tables? What are the column names in `Segreti`? Since you're using an aggregate function (`COUNT()`), you probably need to `GROUP BY` on the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` clause in your query if you're going to meaningfully use an aggregate function.  If you're using MySQL 5.7.5+, I'm surprised you didn't get an error telling you that.  You may have run into the [MySQL Group By Extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) guessing how to group your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax that MySQL allows, but the SQL standard does not -- nor do other databases.  You have a multitude of ungrouped fields in the`SELECT`, but the `COUNT()` turns this into an aggregation query.

With no `group by`, such a query always returns exactly one row.

I would also recommend using table aliases:

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT(rs.id_segreto) as tot
FROM Segreti s INNER JOIN
     Reazioni_Segreti rs
     ON s.id = rs.id_segreto
WHERE rs.tipo_reazione = 'mi_piace'
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY tot DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that the use of `s.id` (rather than listing all the columns) in the `GROUP BY` is allowed -- even under ANSI -- assuming that `id` is defined to be unique in the table.